# What is the use of "-" in the context: "echo $$ $BASHPID | cat -" ? BASH

Tags: bash, shell

The title says it all.

```
echo $$ $BASHPID | cat -;
```

I want to know what the "-" at the end of the above code.
I've come across the usage of "-" similarly in:

```
wget -- <something here> | -
```

I'm going to suppose they are the same...

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, a filename `-` means standard input or standard output, depending on whether it's being used as an input file or output file.

So `cat -` means to read from standard input. This is redundant, because without any arguments `cat` reads from standard input. It's mainly useful when you have other filename arguments, and you want to include stdin, e.g.

```
cat file1 - file2
```

This will insert standard input into the output, between the contents of `file1` and `file2`.

Your second example with `wget` is different. `--` is a special argument that indicates the end of options, and all remaining arguments are data (usually filenames). This is useful in case some of the filename arguments begin with `-`, so they won't be interpreted as options.

`| -` at the end doesn't make sense at all. It pipes the output of `wget` to a program named `-`, but unless you've written such a program, it won't exist.

Comment: Great! I guess in the case: ```echo $$ $BASHPID | cat -;``` this is unnecessary as ```echo $$ $BASHPID | cat;``` would do the same. Is there for some sort of safe guard?

Comment: You don't even need `cat`, just `echo $$ $BASHPID`.

Comment: There is a difference in the output. I think ```$BASHPID``` when run through ```cat``` refers to the process of ```cat``` while ```$$``` still referring to the main process.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Variables are expanded by the original shell.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62231/bashpid-and-differ-in-some-cases for the difference. This whole question really belongs in [unix.se].

Comment: ```root# echo $$ $BASHPID``` -> ```3691 3691``` ```root# echo $$ $BASHPID | cat``` -> ```3691 9975``` yes it does.

Comment: It's the PID of the `echo` command, not `cat`. The pipeline makes it run in a subshell.

Answer (score 1):

According to cat’s [man](http://www.nsc.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?cat) page:

> If file is a single dash (`-') or absent, cat reads from the standard input.”

Which makes it (the dash) redundant in example. Command would behave the same with dash removed.